# Camel route publisher not publishing to JMS outbound queue fails with java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

So I have a route consuming a JMS message from one queue and I want to send it to another queue on the same broker. Blueprint xml pretty simple:

```
<camel:route id="from-jms-consumer-to-jms" trace="false">             
    <from uri="jms:queue:test" />
    <log message="Message consumed :: ${body}" />
    <to uri="jms:queue:other_test" />
</camel:route>
```

But it doesn't work! It consumes and logs the message (so no issue with connection factory) but when it tries to publish it fails with `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException`

Why? I tried everything:

- separate connection factories
- pooling/no-pooling
- transacted/non-transacted

But even a simple route like this fails on the publisher.

This is Camel 3.0.0-M4 and I'm running on Karaf 4.2.1 on JDK 9. There are no other issues. All other components work and have been individually tested.

I even looked at the code for `JmsPublisher` in the Camel source. There's an `isRunAllowed()` `boolean` that returns `false` for `jmsPublisher`. I don't know what I could be missing? Thread pool? JMSHeader on the message? I'm stumped!

Error stack trace:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[from-jms-consumer-] [from-jms-consumer-] [jmsFrom://queue:test                                                          ] [         2]
[from-jms-consumer-] [log7              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[from-jms-consumer-] [to7               ] [jms:queue:other_test                                                          ] [         0]


Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: null
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:140) ~[127:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:130) ~[110:org.apache.camel.camel-base:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryState.run(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:480) [110:org.apache.camel.camel-base:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:185) [110:org.apache.camel.camel-base:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.scheduleMain(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59) [110:org.apache.camel.camel-base:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:87) [110:org.apache.camel.camel-base:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:222) [110:org.apache.camel.camel-base:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:77) [110:org.apache.camel.camel-base:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:40) [143:org.apache.camel.camel-support:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:111) [127:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:3.0.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:245) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076) [167:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:5.0.8.RELEASE_1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got publisher to work using "toD" instead of "to" on the route (https://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html)

Now transaction manager is still throwing an ERROR not being able to LOG a transaction, something about connection not being a "NamedXAResource" wtf that means, but at least the publisher is publishing

Comment: fixed the namexaresource error by removing recoverable transaction manager and just using PlatformTransactionManager or whatevr it is called